# Что выбрать для реализации нейронной сети на NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, нейронные-сети

**Есть задача:** необходимо провести классификацию самолётов и выбрать наиболее подходящее название для каждого из них, которое максимально точно описывает модель.

**Что имеется:** различные названия одного и того же самолёта - `['737', 'B737', 'Boeing 737', 'Boeing 737-800', 'Boeing 737-800 (winglets)']`.

Что нужно: получить на выходе JS Object

```
{
  "Boeing": {
    "737": {
      "Boeing 737-800": ["Boeing 737-800", "Boeing 737-800 (winglets)"]
    }
  }
}
```

Выходит древовидная структура: производитель - семейство - модель.

Почему именно такая классификация: 737, B737, Boeing 737 - всё эти названия не говорят о поколении самолёта, а лишь о его семействе. Под таким названием может скрываться 737-300 - 15-летнее воздушное судно поколения Classic, как 737-900ER - современный самолёт поколения Next Generation. Уточнения `(winglets)` или `(sharklets)` по сути не нужны, но могут свидетельствовать о более близкой дате выпуска самолёта.

Почему именно нейронные сети, а не простой парсинг строк: можно реализовать простую и понятную классификацию с помощью слоёв нейронной сети. Первый слой - производитель, второй слой - семейство, третий слой - модель. Также с выходом новых моделей не нужно дописывать или изменять алгоритмы. Достаточно просто дообучить нейронную сеть.

**Вопрос:** чем и как это можно реализовать? Какие существуют программные инструменты? Стоит ли сходу использовать TensorFlow.js или стоит попробовать что-то попроще сначала?

P.S. - реализовывать планирую на NodeJS, чтобы в дальнейшем иметь возможность быстро интегрировать в браузерной среде.

Answer (score 2):

Нейронная сеть - это когда сначала на ОЧЕНЬ БОЛЬШОМ наборе данных (порядка тысяч и десятков тысяч образцов) сеть обучают, потом на паре тысяч - валидируют, а потом она способна сотни-тысячи образцов объектов "разложить по полочкам".

Отсюда вопрос первый - у вас действительно есть десятки тысяч образцов для обучения? И вопрос второй - у вас будут поступать сотни разных названий, причем иногда таких, каких не было в обучающей выборке и вам надо разбираться, что это за самолет?

Если вы можете вручную построить "простую и понятную" классификацию, то что вы собрались обучать? И главное - зачем???

По моему, вы явно не представляете, что такое нейронная сеть, для каких задач она подходит, а для каких - абсолютно бессмысленна. Что поделать, мода.  Однако для вашей задачи она явно ни к селу ни к городу.